# Passing non selected listboxfor values back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a listboxfor on my view which I populate with a list of users. I can add users to and from this listbox (from another listbox).

I can pass the values back to the contoller but I have to select users in the listbox for this to happen. I don't want to have to select users..just pass back whatever is in the listbox.

On my view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedIDs, DropdownHelper.GetGroupMembers(Model.Id), new { size = 20, @class = "select field small", @style = "width:200px" })
```

In my view model:

```
    public int[] SelectedIDs { get; set; }
```

The controller HtttPost Edit takes the view model and SelectedIDs does contain the ids for the users, but only when selected.

I just don't want to have to select users in the listbox...just passback whatever values are there.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Put the same data in hidden controls and it will post with the form.

Comment: Then don't use listboxes for this. Use a checkboxlist so that users can add or remove users by checking/unchecking a checkbox

Comment: There could be hundreds of users.

Comment: @thegunner, What difference does that make. Whether you scroll though items in a listbox to select them or whether you scroll through a checklistbox is irrelevant.

Comment: If the list of users in the listbox came from the server in the first place then why bother posting them all back again - on postback just get them from the same source which you used to populate the listbox when serving the view?

Comment: Because you might add new users to the listbox or remove users from it. Basically the listbox contains the list of users in a group. I can add users to the group or remove them. Its a pretty standard way of doing this i.e. two listboxes side by side. One containing the group members and the other containing the list of all other users. There is also two buttons  "<" and a ">"to move users. At the moment putting the users/group members Ids in a hidden control seems like the best option (comment 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone will correct me if I missed any, but basically you have five options for passing data to the server:
Cookies
QueryString
Ajax
WebSocket
POST (form variables)

It seems like you want to POST data, so to me hidden inputs is the most appropriate way.